# Emoji support in Google's Cloud Speech API

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I've noticed that certain apps on Android (ie. gboard) support translating phrases such as 'poop emoji' into the actual emoji as part of speech recognition.  I was wondering if this is something that is supported through google's cloud speech APIs that I could similarly use in my own applications?

In my initial scan of the API I can't see anything that might indicate a way to turn this on (ie. `RecognitionConfig` et.al has no obvious toggles for it), and in some quick one-off tests in my own app I wasn't provided emoji-fied results from the service.

I've done a bunch of googling but found nothing so far.

Any insight here would be awesome, thanks!

-edit- Thanks to the answer below I have learned this currently is not supported.   I've gone to Google's issue tracker to request this feature.  If anyone wishes to track the feature request the link is:

https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/113978818

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Cloud Speech-to-Text API** service doesn't currently support **emoji phrases** recognition; however, you can use the **Send Feedback** button located at the lower left and upper right corners of the [service public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/), as well as take a look the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) tool in case you want to raise a Speech API feature request in order to notify to Google about this desired functionality.

Finally, you can refer to the [Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/release-notes) section of **Speech-to-Text API** to keep the track of the new features and functionalities added to the service.

Comment: Awesome answer @Armin_SC, thanks so much.  Perfectly detailed and predicted any follow-up questions I may have.  :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, hopefully this information is useful for you